# blank page when i connect two java-script files with routers and try to display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a doubt in React.js could you please help me. I have created a chat app with firebase and React.js when I connect routers and make a link through two or more Js files its showing a blank page as output in React-app screen what should be done to resolve this .

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.